# Power Automate - Copy List Comments from one Item, Paste Them to Another Item

Tags: httprequest, comments, sharepoint-online, power-automate, listitem

Up front, apologies for no pictures. I can't access Stack Overflow from my workspace; and I can't access my flow from home. Additionally, I'm fairly new to Power Automate, with only about a year under me.

I have created a flow, which effectively archives a SharePoint list item. It takes that item from List A, copies it, then creates a new list item in List B--pasting in all the previous column data into the new item. Pretty easy.

However, I also want to copy the Comments from that list item, and move those Comments to the new item in List B. I've already created a "Send HTTP request..." using GET to acquire the original comment data (code below). I've tested it, and it works.

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('[List Name]')/items('[ID]')/Comments

"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
"content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
```

However, after I've created the new list item in List B, how do I paste this data in, so that the comment button?

I've tried several things, each with failed results:

I've tried utilizing the PUT, PATCH and DELETE methods for HTTP requests. Apparently, /Comments does not support those methods. This means I'm stuck with GET and POST.

So, in my 2nd HTTP request, I utilized the POST method. In the 'body' section of the request, I used the following expression:

```
outputs('Send_an_HTTP_request_to_SharePoint')?['body']['d']['results']
```

This continues to error out. I'm convinced I'm making some kind of rudimentary mistake. Can someone show me an example of how they've done this?

Comment: Through help on Reddit, I was able to copy/paste the comment text itself. However, I was not able to preserve the original commenter, or the original date of the comment. Here's a link so people can see the HTTP data and outputs: https://imgur.com/nSIKHTE